# Recommended AWS service or method to stream data from S3 into database tables

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-ec2, product

Currently business is trying to store the data in an Amazon S3 bucket. We are trying to load it into a Relational database table using a data load utility tool in the same ec2 instance where DB is located. Unfortunately, we have to download the file from S3 into the EC2 instance where the database is installed or located.

The business also says they cannot use JDBC port or afford to use a VPN Connection.

Database Name: MYSQL

Utility tool: (Utility tool must use)Business proprietary ($BPLOADUTIL -CSV --table T_BPARTNER --file local3gbfile.csv)

Can we do a data load via HTTPS and use the utility tool at the same time? do you propose any services or products that can do the expected?

Expected: Not to download the file into the EC2 instance where the database is located but at the same time, I need to load the data from the ec2 instance using the utility tool.
The solution can include (Services, Products suggestions, Web apps, or anything ) but the connection should be HTTPS only

Comment: If the tool expects a CSV file and only supports local files then you would either need to download the CSV file from S3 to local disk or mount S3 as a remote file system (e.g. using s3fs-fuse or riofs).

Comment: _WHY_ do you not want to download the file onto the EC2 instance?

Comment: Otherwise, I cannot run the utility to upload the data into the table. but I think @Jarmod has the simplest solution of using s3fs-fuse and riofs. but is this approach secure? can we also configure KMS? with there be security incursion or attack or vulnerabilities?

Comment: @AshleyGabby, If you liked the answer and it worked for you, kindly upvote it as well as recommended by Stack Overflow.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot connect to a database without using the proper protocol. For example, MySQL uses TCP protocol and connects over default port of 3306. You cannot connect to database using HTTP/HTTPs protocol using port 80/443.

You can use AWS Database Migration Service to load data in CSV format from S3 to any relational database even the one residing on an EC2 instance without downloading the file on the EC2 instance.